# How to retrieve particular emp object from a list without looping through datastructure

Tags: java

I have 65000 records of employees in a database . i am retreiving all the records and storing as employee object in a list  as a cache. when customer enters the emp id in the browser , the record should be fetched from the list on one condition , without looping through the list. how can we acheive it.

using indexOf(Object ) we can acheive ,by implementing equals method , but what business logic should go in that.kindly let me know your views.

```
class Employee
{
 private int id;
 private String name;
 Private String address;


 public void setAddress (){} 

 public void setId(){}

 public void setName(){}

// simillarly getMethods
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I would implement a cache based on a hashmap rather than a list:

```
Map cache = new HashMap<Integer, Employee>();
```

This way you can retrieve an Employee object by a given ID very efficiently.

Additionally, I wouldn't add a setter for the employee id, since it can corrupt the mapping. Consider setting the id through a constructor parameter only.

--EDIT--

If you MUST use a list:

2) You may want to sort it first. This will allow performing a binary search (See [Collections.binarySearch(..)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T%29) methods). This requires implementing a [Comparator](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) or the [Comparable](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface, in order to define an ordering between the Employee objects. Also, you will have to create a dummy Employee object with the required id each time you want to perform the search.

3) If performance is not an issue, simply use [List.indexOf(..)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29). This requires implementing the equals(..) method in the Employee class.

4) In order to do it really without loops, you can create a sparse list, containing Employee with id N at index N. This is only feasible if the Employee id value range is not too big. The benefit is an optimal retrieval time.

Comment: @Eyal i dont want using  Map. only by List .

Comment: @Eyal any idea how to do in list!!

Comment: @Suresh S: @Eyal Schneider's suggestion is pretty much the best solution in your case. Why would you prefer a list over a Map if you want access-by-key?

Comment: this was a interview questions,intially i suggested using HashMap,but she was asking to use list.

Comment: @Eyal thanks for the idea. what logic must go in to equals method to return particular object.

Comment: @Suresh S: check http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#equals(java.lang.Object) .